# Can I use an external Wi-Fi USB adapter as a mobile hotspot on Windows 10 (without Command Prompt)?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, usb

I have a laptop which has built-in Wi-Fi, but I want to use the internet and share the internet as a hotspot at the same time. In Windows 10, if I select to share over Internet and then switch the Share to other devices option on, it automatically turns it off right after. The only option that works is Bluetooth but it's slow. I don't really want to use Command Prompt to get this to work either.

End goal: Share internet via external adapter and use built-in internet as usual.

[image: Windows hotspot screen]

The option that keeps turning itself off is the 'Share internet with other devices'. I suspect it's because the laptop won't have internet because it can only share and not receive so it turns itself off? I'm not sure. This is why I want to use an external one. It only stays turned on if I use the `Bluetooth` option, but as I've said before it's really slow.

So, how do I make a mobile hotspot on Windows 10 using an external USB Wi-Fi adapter as the hotspot without Command Prompt?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of exactly what you are turning on that is then immediately turning itself off?

Comment: @Ramhound I edited the post :)

Comment: On the device you're attempting to connect to this device, you are finding the WiFi access point, that is created by the wireless adapter and trying to connect to it?  Once you do I assume that device does NOT have internet access?

Comment: AFAIK the standard Windows feature only allow sharing the internet from other devices to WiFi. In order to use the same WiFi device there are 3rd party solutions like the old Connectify https://connectify.me/

Comment: @Ramhound so you have Laptop 1 which is the Windows laptop that I want to use a USB Wi-Fi adapter with, and Laptop 2 is the laptop that needs to connect to the hotspot produced by the Windows laptop. So, Laptop 1 creates the hotspot USING the external Wi-Fi adapter, so that it doesn't disable the sharing option instantly and laptop 2 is the one who will connect to the hotspot. I need Laptop 1 to share the internet from the Wi-Fi card to external Wi-Fi adapter (to create the hotspot)

Comment: I know it's a bit complicated, but I can't really explain it any better.